# GORM ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm building a very small application in order to learn Golang and I'm using [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) with [GORM](https://gorm.io/) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) for a simple CRUD. The thing is that i'm always getting this `ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502` error when creating a new user. I've searched on the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html), but it always seems that GORM should automatically handle ID creation and stuff.

This is my model:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID    int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primarykey"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}
```

This is the function I'm using for user creation:

```golang
func CreateUser(c echo.Context) error {
    // Parse input data
    user := &models.User{}
    if err := c.Bind(user); err != nil {
        errorMessage := lib.Message{Message: "Failed to parse new user data: " + err.Error()}
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
    }

    fmt.Println(user) // debug

    // Creating new entry
    db := storage.GetDBInstance()
    if err := db.Create(user).Error; err != nil {
        errorMessage := lib.Message{Message: "Failed to create new user: " + err.Error()}
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
    }
    return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, user)
}
```

This is the command I'm using for testing:

```sh
curl -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"name":"Joe Smith", "email":"joe.smith@example.com"}' \
  localhost:1323/users
```

And finally, this is the output I'm getting:

```
⇨ http server started on [::]:1323
&{0 Joe Smith joe.smith@example.com}

2021/03/12 13:56:10 /home/gabriel-milan/go/src/github.com/gabriel-milan/echo-rest-api/api/controllers/user.go:89 ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)
[2.749ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "users" ("name","email") VALUES ('Joe Smith','joe.smith@example.com') RETURNING "id"
{"time":"2021-03-12T13:56:10.125834131-03:00","id":"","remote_ip":"::1","host":"localhost:1323","method":"POST","uri":"/users","user_agent":"curl/7.64.0","status":500,"error":"","latency":3377762,"latency_human":"3.377762ms","bytes_in":53,"bytes_out":144}
```

In my model declaration, I've also tried `gorm:"primaryKey"`, `gorm:"primary_key"`, setting default values to an UUID function, inheriting from `gorm.Model`... but none of it seems to work.

My requirements (for version checking):

```
require (
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.2.1
    github.com/lib/pq v1.6.0 // indirect
    gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.0.8 // indirect
    gorm.io/gorm v1.21.3 // indirect
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out:

When I was creating the `users` table, this is what I was doing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);
```

and then it just hit me and I remember that this does not increment automatically. After I've fixed my query to

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id SERIAL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);
```

it works like a charm.